# Can't use void()

Tags: c++, codeblocks

i'm having an issue with my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void displayEnnemyStatus(ennemyAttackPoints, ennemyHealthPoints)        // Call this function to      display
{                                                                       // ennemy related     informations
    cout << endl << "Ennemy health points: " << ennemyHealthPoints;
    cout << endl << "Ennemy attack points: " << ennemyAttackPoints << endl;
}

int main()
{

    //Player related variables
    int healthPointsMax(100);
    int actionPointsMax(100);
    int recoveryPoints(100);
    int healthPoints(100);
    int actionPoints(100);
    int attackPoints(100)
    //Player related variables

    //Ennemy related variables
    int ennemyHealthPoints(230);
    int ennemyAttackPoints(10);
    //Ennemy related variables

    //Main variables
    string stringInput;
    //Main variables

    //TEXT

    cout << "HP: " << healthPoints << endl;
    cout << "AP: " << actionPoints << endl;
    cout << "RP: " << recoveryPoints << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "HP = Health Points, AP = Action Points, RP = Recovery Points" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "CONTROLS:" << endl;
    cout << "attack [ennemy name]  //attacks the ennemy" << endl;
    cout << "heal [playername]  // heals the selected player" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "A wild nugget appears!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;

    // TEXT

    getline(cin, stringInput);
    if (stringInput = attack ennemy)
    {
        cout << endl << "You dealt 100 attack points to: ENNEMY" << endl;
        ennemyHealthPoints = ennemyHealthPoints - attackPoints;
        displayEnnemyStatus(ennemyHealthPoints, ennemyAttackPoints);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The debugger says that there is a problem with the fonction "void displayEnnemyStatus"

I checked every variable, there is no problem with that.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, what does the debugger say exactly?

Comment: *"The debugger says that there is a problem..."* and what exactly does it say that problem is? Copy the error code word for word.

Comment: Your function declaration is incorrect. You need to provide the types of the parameters. This code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Also `if (stringInput = attack ennemy)` should be `if (stringInput == "attack enemy")` ... I think

Comment: The compiler says that that the the variables needed are not declared.

Comment: @juanchopanza His compiler might only give a warning for implicit declaration of variables to `int`.  However, this does not appear to be the case considering his comment.

Comment: @Namfuak That wouldn't be C++.

Comment: i fixed a few things, including syntax errors in the first "if" statement. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Enemy only has one 'n' http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enemy?s=t

Comment: Oh. I didn't know for enemy, i'm french. But thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :-

```
if (stringInput == "attack ennemy")
   {
     cout << endl << "You dealt 100 attack points to: ENNEMY" << endl;
     ennemyHealthPoints = ennemyHealthPoints - attackPoints;
     **displayEnnemyStatus(ennemyAttackPoints, ennemyHealthPoints)**;
   }
```

Instead of :-

```
   if (stringInput = attack ennemy)
{
    cout << endl << "You dealt 100 attack points to: ENNEMY" << endl;
    ennemyHealthPoints = ennemyHealthPoints - attackPoints;
    displayEnnemyStatus(ennemyHealthPoints, ennemyAttackPoints);
```

Comment: I tried, but it's still undeclared at line 7 (where i declare the function "void displayEnnemyStatus")

Comment: Correct this line void (int ennemyHealthPoints, int ennemyAttackPoints)